# RequireJS require-less and require-css pathing

Tags: javascript, requirejs, less

I'm using the require-less plugin [require-less](https://github.com/guybedford/require-less) along with the require-css plugin.

My paths are getting messed up when LESS files are used but NOT when CSS files are used.

My paths looks like:

```
'css!assets/fontello/fontello-codes',
'less!assets/bootstrap/bootstrap',
```

My url is:

```
http://localhost/phoenix
```

when the LESS files get requested they end up with:

```
'http://localhost/phoenix/phoenix/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.less'
```

I'm setting my base URL to:

```
 baseUrl: "./phoenix/"
```

If I do `less!../assets/bootstrap/bootstrap` it works but not if the paths change of course.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Have you tried using the `relativeUrls: true` option?

Answer (score 0):

`baseUrl: "./phoenix/"` works from the location the require.js configuration file is situated, lets say init.js, so if it is in `localhost/phoenix` and you put that baseUrl location is working as expected, you could either remove your baseUrl or level up in your folder structure that init.js file.